# Change author of entry within Craft Client licence

Tags: users

I created some sample blog posts during development, and now want to change the author of those posts to the client. Yet, only I'm listed in the dropdown box when I try and change an entry's author.

Any ideas? Besides editing it in the database.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't edit the database?  Seems like the most straight forward way.

Comment: No, just convenience. I'll have to do it that way. All I need to update is the author_id in craft_entries, right?

Comment: That should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the database: author_id column in the craft_entries table.

Comment: "Besides editing it in the database" :)

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I know. It's a sign of defeat.

Answer (score 2):

Can you edit the client's permissions settings so that he can edit and/or create entries? Because that's what necessary with the "Pro" package.

Another idea is to just rename your account, change the email and make it the client's.

Comment: No, you can't edit permissions. I just assumed you'd be able to do that. Will make a feature request, maybe.

Comment: @Clive What about the rename idea?

Comment: Nah, that way they're the admin, right?

Comment: Ok, that's probably not that what you want. Didn't think about that. X)